# Text converted to mesh

Tags: text-object

I was wondering how to convert text to a mesh? I have tried using a variety of keys including Alt + C but no Convert To Mesh option appears. (new blender noob user here)

Comment: It works for me.  It doesn't EXACTLY say "Convert To Mesh" but you should get a popup menu with two options.   Are you on a Mac or Windows?

Comment: Only works in Object mode. In Edit mode the menu will not popup. Could it be this? Or maybe your text is a mesh already...

Answer (score 8):

In Blender 2.8 and higher, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> isn't assigned to a command. But you can assign to it to the menu command *Object > Convert To > Mesh*. (Right-click the menu entry to the assign shortcut.)

*Convert To Mesh* works in *Object Mode* when the text is selected.

Answer (score 1):

To convert the text, press Alt+C in Object mode with the text selected, and select "Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text", this will convert the text to a 3d mesh and you will not be able write letters like before.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For more complex (and better looking :-) ) meshes with text, you may want to look at my program Pomelo. See:

https://github.com/dov/pomelo

Pomelo creates the meshes, that may then be imported into blender for further processing.

Here is an example of the kind of meshes that you can create with Pomelo, that would be very difficult to create natively in Blender.

[image: Pomelo generated mesh imported into Blender]